# Devise - how to show user's post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I use Devise gem for authentication.

In database I have users table and posts table in my database schema (and Post controller).
In post controller I want to find all posts assigned to specific user. I have user_id in posts table.

How to get all user's posts or how to check if specific post is assigned for SIGNED IN user.

I thought about something like this (of course is only pseudocode:

> current_user.id == Post.where(params:[post_id]).user_id

So how to get current user id in Devise and how to check the current user id is the same like eg. user_id assigned to viewing post (I want to add 'edit' function when current user is post owner) and how to find all post which current user is owner.

Answer (score 4):

**Associations**

Firstly, your `user_id` column in your `posts` table is what's known as a [**foreign_key**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Foreign keys are used in relational database systems to give you the ability to call associative data from a single record. Simply, it means that you'll be able to use the [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to call the data you require, rather than having to call it individually:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following call:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = current_user.posts
   end
end
```

You'll be best served looking up the [`has_many` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]

---

**Fix**

In regards to showing your posts for your users, you need to be sure that you have the correct "flow" set up. What I mean is you need some condition to know whether your user is signed in & that `@posts` is set:

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% if @posts.present? %>
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= post.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the first time you use Devise. You can access `current_user` inside controllers or views. I imagine you could do something like this

In controller (`posts_controller.rb`):

```
@posts = current_user.posts
```

In view (`posts/show.html.erb`, I guess):

```
if current_user.id = @post.current_user
   #render something here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all post which current user is owner.

```
@posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

and on your view

```
<%-# commented : checking if @posts is empty -%>
<% if @posts.empty? %> 
  <span>Sorry, post is empty </span>
<% else %>
  <%= @posts.each do |p| %>
   <% if p.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <% link_to "edit", edit_path(p) %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could get current_user posts. I'll go the long way.

## we need

- an action
- an action view and a partial
- a route
- a link_to

*** action ***

```
def my_posts
  @posts = current_user.posts.all.order(created_at: 'DESC')
end
```

*** view ***

*my_posts.html.erb*

```
<% if @posts.present? %>
  <%= render 'posts' posts: @posts %>
<% else %>
   <h1>You don't have any posts yet! create one</h1>
<% end %>
```

*_posts.html.erb*

```
<%posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

*index.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'posts' posts: @posts %>
```

***route***

```
get 'post' => 'posts#my_posts', as: :my_posts
```

***link_to***

```
<%= link_to 'My posts', my_posts_path %>
```

I may be late but someone can find it useful :)